# Dynamically add cells to table with fixed number of columns in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to create a table with 5 columns. From there, I'll add cells as I see fit, automatically moving to the next row when the column is filled.I'm populating each cell with info from a row in a DataTable object. If you can imagine, the table will remain a fixed width, but grow in height as more items are added. Repeaters, maybe? I also have Telerik UI for AJAX, so if that route is a possibility, I'm open to it.

Code:

```
//create empty table with 5 columns here
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
     TableCell cell = new TableCell();

     // I have the logic figured out to fill the cell here
     // Now, how to insert these into the table, automatically moving to the next row when necessary
}
```

Comment: I think you want to update the row where the cells are empty not insert. insert means adding new rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    // Suppose you want to add 10 rows
    int totalRows = 10;
    int totalColumns = 5;

    for (int r = 0; r <= totalRows; r++)
    {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
        for (int c = 0; c <= totalColumns; c++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
            txtBox.Text = "Row: " + r + ", Col:" + c;
            cell.Controls.Add(txtBox);
            //Add the cell to the current row.
            tableRow.Cells.Add(cell);

            if (c==5)
            {
                // This is the final column, add the row
                table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

This way you can add any dynamic number of rows for your table, each row will contain your 5 columns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I had the same idea! I am going to try this on Monday. Thank you.